# Eigendecomposition of hyper-complex multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, quaternions, hypercomplex-numbers

There is an isomorphism between quaternions and $4\times 4$ matrices:
$$
\phi: a+bi+cj+dk \longmapsto \begin{pmatrix}
a&b&c&d \\
-b&a&-d&c\\
-c&d&a&-b\\
-d&-c&b&a
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Matrices of such kind have a peculiar eigendecomposition. To be more specific, they have $2$ eigenvalues $\lambda = a \pm i \sqrt{b^2+c^2+d^2}$, each with a $2$-dimensional eigenspace spanned on
$$
e_1 = \begin{pmatrix}b \\ \pm i\sqrt{b^2+c^2+d^2} \\ d \\ -c\end{pmatrix},
e_2 = \begin{pmatrix}\pm i\sqrt{b^2+c^2+d^2} \\ b \\ c \\ d\end{pmatrix}
$$

**Q1**: What's actually going on? Is there a simple and direct way to explain this?

**Q2**: Is it possible to generalize this result to know the eigendecomposition of the stuff that you get in the Cayley-Dickson procedure beyond quaternions? Even without an isomorphism, you still can represent a multiplication by a particular hypercomplex number with a matrix, so I'd be curious in its eigendecomposition.

**UPD:** Some motivation behind the question is that if we ignore the signs, we get a much simpler eigendecomposition:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a&b&c&d \\
b&a&d&c\\
c&d&a&b\\
d&c&b&a
\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{4}H_4
\operatorname{diag}\begin{pmatrix}
a+b+c+d\\
a-b+c-d\\
a+b-c-d\\
a-b-c+d
\end{pmatrix} H_4,
$$

where $H_4$ is the Walsh matrix:

$$
H_4 = \begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1 \\
1&-1&1&-1\\
1&1&-1&-1\\
1&-1&-1&1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Knowing this, I was hoping for an interesting structure here as well.

Comment: Any non-real quaternion spans a subalgebra isomorphic to $\mathbb C$, since $\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2+d^2}}(bi+cj+dk)$ is a square root of $-1$. I suspect this observation should explain at least some of what you noted.